# How to disable cocoapods cache

Tags: cocoapods

Does anyone know if its possible to disable the cocoapods cache, specifically when running a pod install?

I'm working a Jenkins slave that does multiple builds that seems to conflict with the cache. I really do not need a cache in the first place, but it's nice to have.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it by creating a `~/.cocoapods/config.yaml` file with the following contents.

```
skip_download_cache: true
```

After this CocoaPods won't use `~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods`.

(http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cocoapods/Pod/Config#skip_download_cache-instance_method)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had problems when pod install failed to work because files in cache were readonly... couple of days wasted searching for a solution trying different things and this is finaly it.